# Modeling and Showing Columns from Multiple Tables in the List View

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xamarin.forms, datagrid, azure-sql-database

In the list view of my Xamarin Forms' app(or in the datagridview of a desktop application), I'd like to show the records queried from 3 tables. Below are the 3 tables, which are stored in my Azure SQL database account. (I'm using a separate ASP.Net Core REST API Web application published on Azure to communicate between my app and my Azure database.)

[image]

Currently, I'm showing only the records from tblMoney, not from the other two tables. Here's the part where the listview is filled with the tblMoney records.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private const string Url = "https://testwebapi.azurewebsites.net/tblmoney";
    private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    private ObservableCollection<TblMoney> _tblmoney_items;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
        var tblmoney_items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TblMoney>>(content);

        _tblmoney_items = new ObservableCollection<TblMoney>(tblmoney_items);
        moneyListView.ItemsSource = _tblmoney_items;

        base.OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

The following is the model class for tblMoney.

```
public partial class TblMoney
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RecordDate { get; set; }
    public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
    public int? AmountOut { get; set; }
    public int? SpentTypeId { get; set; }
    public int? PayMethodId { get; set; }

    public virtual TblSpentType SpentType { get; set; }
    public virtual TblPayMethod PayMethod { get; set; }
}
```

In the list view of the MainPage, I want to show, along with other tblMoney columns, the PayMethodName and TypeDesc columns, each of which are stored in tblPayMethod and tblSpentType, respectively.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is there a way you can create a SQL query that extracts the records from all of the 3 tables, using INNER JOINs and assign the SQL query to the data source(ItemsSource property) of the list view?
2. How do you create a model class that represents all of the columns from all 3 tables? Currently, I have only TblMoney class which represents only tblMoney. Do you have to create such model class as representing all columns of the 3 tables and declare an ObservableCollection of the model class type in the MainPage class to show the collection items in the list view?
3. As far as I know, Entity Framework Core (which I'm not familiar with but somehow guess would be possibly helpful for the above tasks) sits between the application and the database. Should I take advantage of Entity Framework to carry out the above tasks? If so, how?

I'm asking these questions before taking a series of online course for Entity Framework. I'm not 100% sure it will teach me requisite knowledge to do all of the above. Please help. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: have you written your own WebAPI code that is running on Azure?

Comment: @Jason Yeah, I have.

Comment: Then do your join in the API code and return that model to the mobile client